# Access session variable with Jquery in jsp page separated from javascript file

Tags: jquery, html, session-variables

I have got a requirement where I am doing an ajax request from javascript file in myPage.jsp , the servResource Method is getting called where it queries the DB and returns a list of objects and that I'm adding it to the session attribute, now I want to get that session attribute from javascript file in myPage.jsp (from javascript file in myPage.jsp page where ajax request was invoked). `alert(state);` does not work. Is there any way by which I can achieve this.

```
function getStateList() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "getStateNames.do",
        success : function(data) {
            var combo = $("#state");
            combo.empty();
            combo.append("<option value=''>-SELECT STATE NAME-</option>");
            var state = "${sessionScope.user.state}";
            alert(state);//IT DOES NOT WORKED 
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(k, v) {
                if (state == v.statecode) {
                    combo.append("<option value=" + v.statecode + " selected>"
                            + v.statename + "</option>");
                } else {
                    combo.append("<option value=" + v.statecode + ">"
                            + v.statename + "</option>");
                }
            });
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("No State details found");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Rather than adding list of object into session you can convert list of object into json and get that json on ajax success .

Comment: Kandarp I did not added list of objects into session. my question is how do i get the session variable property to compare it with the list of json objects